# How to redirect http and ssh to other vms based on subdomain?

Tags: traefik, lxc, proxmox

I have several subdomains:

`server1.domain.com  ---->  VM1
server2.domain.com  ---->  VM2 
server3.domain.com  ---->  VM3`

I would like to use traefik in order to create a transparent proxy so that when a HTTP request arrives on the server where traefik is installed, it is redirected to the corresponding VM. I would like to do the same to SSH traffic.

VM's are containers (LXC) and the virtualization management software is ProxMox.

Could someone kindly help me?

Comment: Use a [proxy device](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/containers.md#type-proxy) and point them domains to the server ip, though with http(s) its better to put a reverse proxy in front like nginx. Or do pre routing with iptables etc.

Comment: I think proxmox doesn't supports LXD.